# how to determine the time complexity of this nested for loop

Tags: algorithm

I want to calculate the complexity of this nested for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
            //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

How do you calculate the complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- actually,this three for loops is a good ways to get the number of all
  the different combinations of choosing 3 elements of n elements.
- it
  is equal to C(n, 3). and C(n, i) -> O(n^i).
- **so the answer is O(n^3).**

Comment: what if you don't treat it as a combination problem?

Comment: can you think of any other place which can be used?

Answer (score 1):

How many times do you reach the body of the inner loop?

This selects every combination of 3 elements from [0,n) (into i,j,k)

There are n*(n-1)*(n-2) / 3! = (n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n) / 6 of these.

The complexity of this is O(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: there are 3 loops, each loop is averagely O(n) time complexity.

So it is O(n^3).